# I'm trying adding a to a string a char every 2 seconds, but it diesn't work, no errors in a console. Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, settimeout

I know task is super simple. But I do not why it's not working.
Here is a code below how I implemented, as far as I checked `this.showStr += this.mainStr.charAt(i)` there is no mistake in this part is just something wrong with connection loop and setTimer. Does anybody see an error ?

```
  data(){
      return {
        mainStr: "Hello, my name is Eldar and I'm web-developer",
        showStr: ''
      }
  },
  methods:{
      showString() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.mainStr.length; ++i) {
          this.delay(i);
        }
      },
    delay(i){
      function delay() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.showStr += this.mainStr.charAt(i)
        }, 2000)
      }
    }
  },
  mounted(){
      this.showString();
  }
```

---

Ohh I'm sorry I published the wrong code. Here is a code which doesnt work

```
<template>
    <p>{{ showStr }}</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "GreetingTitle.vue",
      data(){
          return {
            mainStr: "Hello, my name is Eldar and I'm web-developer",
            showStr: ''
          }
      },
      methods:{
          showString() {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.mainStr.length; ++i) {
              this.delay(i);
            }
          },
        delay(i){
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.showStr += this.mainStr.charAt(i)
            }, 2000)
        }
      },
      mounted(){
          this.showString();
      }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: You have `delay` function inside `delay(i)` function... Maybe one of this is incorrect?

Comment: You never call the inner `delay` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is that you set all timers in one time. You need to set different timers for calling your function time by time with interval, like that:

```js
const mainStr = "Hello, my name is Eldar and I'm web-developer";
let showStr = '';

for (let i = 0; i < mainStr.length; ++i) {
  delay(i);
}

function delay(i){
  setTimeout(() => {
    showStr += mainStr.charAt(i)
    console.log(showStr);
  }, 300 * i)
}
```

**UP: Vue version (for dummies):**

```js
new Vue({
  name: "GreetingTitle.vue",
  data(){
      return {
        mainStr: "Hello, my name is Eldar and I'm web-developer",
        showStr: ''
      }
  },
  methods:{
      showString() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.mainStr.length; ++i) {
          this.delay(i);
        }
      },
    delay(i){
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.showStr += this.mainStr.charAt(i)
        }, 300 * i)
    }
  },
  mounted(){
      this.showString();
  }
}).$mount('#container');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
    <p>{{ showStr }}</p>
</div>
```